# MySQL count total number of rows

Tags: mysql, count

I have a complicated MySQL query which takes a lot of time, selecting from a table with more than 150k rows and several JOINS and subqueries. I am limiting the amount of results, but I need to know the total amount of rows.

Is there a way not to repeat the query with `COUNT(*)` as the field to get them? (repeating the query almost doubles the amount of time the script takes to complete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may actually be faster to make the two queries (so you may just want to do some quick testing):

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

In any case, try to make sure that the COUNT(*) can use the index (it will say "using index" in the Extra column if you use EXPLAIN query)

You could also consider caching the COUNT(*) result if it doesn't have to be exact (as you're limiting your result).

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has a clause called `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` which you put after `SELECT` and before any field names. Then you call a second query which is just `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows` and it gives you how many rows the previous query found.

Comment: More info on that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows